# Obtaining youtube embedded video code through php

Tags: php

I am a new learner to php. I am trying to retrieve embeded information from youtube videos URLs.  I was originally following the code from this [SITE](http://google.com) but unfortunately the author doesn't provide access to actual code.

I am having difficulties extracting the php variable values so that i can get the embedded video code.

The htmlentities echo is returning this error`syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

source: [SITE](http://google.com)

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="">
    URL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" value="<?php $vari ?>" name="yurl"> <!--$vari-->
    <br>
    <br>
    Height:&nbsp;
    <input type="text" value="<?php $hth ?>" name="yheight"> <!--$hth-->
    <br>
    <br>
    Width:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" value="<?php $wdth ?>" name="ywidth"> <!--$wdth-->
    <br>
    <br>
    Autoplay:&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php $auto1; $auto2; ?>" name="yautop">  <!--$auto1 $auto2-->
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Embed Code" name="ysubmit">
    </form>
</html>
```

**php code for getting youtube url info**

```
<?php
$vari ='';
$step1 =explode ('v=', $vari);
$step2 =explode ('&amp;',$step1[1]);

$auto1='?autoplay=1';

$auto2='&autoplay=1';


//Iframe code with autoplay
echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step2[0].$auto1'"
frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>';

//embed code with autoplay
echo htmlentities ('<embed width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$step2[0].$auto2'"
wmode="transparent" embed="" /></embed>');
?>
```

Comment: Having difficulty? Can you show the end result of what you are currently doing?

Comment: Yes, well the echo htmlentities is returning this error `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code... Should Work

```
<?php
$vari ='';

if($_POST)
{
    $vari       = $_POST['yurl'];
    $hth        = $_POST['yheight'];
    $wdth       = $_POST['ywidth'];
    $is_auto    =   0;

    $step1 =explode ('v=', $vari);
    $step2 =explode ('&amp;',$step1[1]);

    if(isset($_POST['yautop'] ))
    {
        if($_POST['yautop'] == 1)
            $is_auto    =   1;
    }
    $auto1  = '?autoplay='.$is_auto;
    $auto2  = '&autoplay='.$is_auto;

//Iframe code with autoplay

echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://ww.youtube.com/embed/'.$step2[0].$auto1.'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');

//embed code with autoplay
echo htmlentities ('<embed width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$step2[0].$auto2.'" wmode="transparent" embed="" /></embed>');
}
?>
```

Problems were

1. concatenation operator (.) was missing
2. variable name was invalid for **"$atuo1"**
3. post block was missing.

---

Updates

please replace iframe line with below one (note : one "w" was missing in URL it was "ww")

```
echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step2[0].$auto1.'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');
```

Comment: +1 thank you for documenting the changes and adding necessary code. The  only issue now is that the autoplay when checked is not echoing the right value of "1". Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/youtube_video/)

Comment: Updated code. PLease check once... Now if you want force auto load you can update  $is_auto = 0 to **$is_auto = 1**

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a concatenation operator `(.)` after `$step2[0].$auto2` and `$step2[0].$auto1` in both the echo blocks.

> ```
> echo htmlentities (...)
> ```

It should be:

```
 echo htmlentities ('<embed width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/"'.$step2[0].$auto2.'"wmode="transparent" embed="" /></embed>');
```

Also, in your Iframe code with autoplay
you have misspelled `$auto1`. That wouldn't generate an error, but it wont work right.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below function to get the embed url code from both facebook and youtube 
the $link is the address shown on the web browser as it is

```
//get youtube link
    function youtube_embed_link($link){
        $new=str_replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','', $link);
        $link='https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$new;
        return $link;
    }
    //get facebook link
    function fb_embed_link($link) {
        $link = 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href='.$link.'&show_text=0&width=560';
        return $link;
    }
//get embed url for fb nd youtube
function get_vid_embed_url($link){
    $embed_url='sss';
//if video link is facebook
    if (strpos($link, 'facebook') !== false) {
        $embed_url=fb_embed_link($link);
    }
//if video link is youtube
    if (strpos($link, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
        $embed_url=youtube_embed_link($link);
    }
    return $embed_url;
}
```